# How to play audio files one after the other

Tags: android, audio

I have multiple audio files in the assets directory of my application. When the user clicks a button I want to play those files in a certain order, one after the other. There shouldn't be any noticeable lag between the audio files. What is the best approach to achieve this?

I am thinking of using `MediaPlayer` objects and `OnCompletionListener`s. But, that would mean I have to create a lot of `OnCompletionListener`s because I need to know every time which audio file is next. Am I missing something or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are on the right way, don't need a lot of OnCompletionListener´s.

```
//define a variable to be used as index.
int audioindex = 0;
//Extract the files into an array
String[] files = null;
files = assetManager.list("audiofiles");
```

then in your OnCompletionListener.

```
 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
    // @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // File has ended, play the next one.
   FunctionPlayFile(files[audioindex]);
   audioindex+=1; //increment the index to get the next audiofile
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this, these classes can play mp3 urls one after another, i created them roughly at some point,and can be tweaked for playing from asset........

https://github.com/vivdub/AndroidMediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

create raw folder in res directory and put your sound file there

Now... Use PlayMedia Like this

```
int[] soundIDs = {R.raw.yes, R.raw.eat};
PlayMedia playAudio = new PlayMedia(context,soundIDs);
playAudio.execute();
```

and define PlayMedia Class Like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class PlayMedia extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = PlayMedia.class.getSimpleName();

    Context context;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int[] soundIDs;
    int idx =1;

    public PlayMedia(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
    }
    public PlayMedia(final Context context, final int[] soundIDs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.soundIDs=soundIDs;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,soundIDs[0]);
        setNextMediaForMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
    }

    public void setNextMediaForMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer player){
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {         
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(soundIDs.length>idx){
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,soundIDs[idx]);
                    setNextMediaForMediaPlayer(mp);
                    mp.start();
                    idx+=1;
                }               
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "", e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "", e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the audio suddenly stops after 4-5 secs...do you know why is that happening?