# Play music in android

Tags: android, audio

I want to play a number of sound files in raw directory one after another in android.
How to do that?
Please anyone provide me an example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class documentation. You will all information there.

Want more, get the Android Media Player code

Comment: How to play a list of files?
I want to make it a variable.
eg:mp = MediaPlayer.create(geetaact.this, R.raw.first);
//first should change by taking value from /raw folder.

Comment: use setDataSource function to play another file.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this **[How to play audio files one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288513/how-to-play-audio-files-one-after-the-other)** the code here will help you to play audio files one after another from assets directory.