# How to play two mp4-files after each other without noticeable lag -in C/C++

Tags: c++, video-encoding

What is the best way to make a function-call from c/c++ code to play two short mp4-files sequentially after each other meeting the below constraint:
I want them to be played in such a way that it won't be noticed that there are two separate files.

I will have hundreds of short mp4-files and want to play all of these sequentially without that the viewer noticing it.
One way would be to separate the mp4-files into their frames -- if there is some kind of player which can be fed with frames. 
The easiest would be something like this, but a library for c/c++: [How to play audio files one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288513/how-to-play-audio-files-one-after-the-other) .. 
I don't know how well it works though.

I am looking for code of how to do this.

Comment: Do you have a particular video-playback API in mind that you want to use, or are you shopping around for one?  I suppose you could always instantiate two video-playback widgets (from whatever API you use), and use them to double buffer (i.e. load up the first video in widget A and the preload second video in widget B, and hide A and show B at the moment when A's video ends, then repeat as necessary)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to use FFMpeg, but I am flexible. It is an interesting idea that I might test if not finding a way to separate a mp4-file into frames; and feed a video-playback widget with these frames.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use C++ at all--just use any old video editing program to concatenate the files into one, and play that with any normal player.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I forgot to mention that I will receive the files continiously. I don't have all of the files at once. It may happen that I have only 2 files when starting; and while playing these two files, I will receive a third file, etc.

Comment: So it's like a torrent program that streams video?  Perhaps you can find an open-source torrent program that does this already?  If not, I suggest writing some code against DirectX or whatever and coming back to SO when you have specific questions about your implementation.